# Local domain cookies blocked by IE/Edge

Tags: php, internet-explorer, cookies

I have a wierd issue with IE and Edge - they appear to be blocking cookies on my local machine where the domain points to my PC.

So I have a domain http://mydomain.local/cookie.php with the following code:

```
<?php
setcookie('my','cookie',0);
print '<pre>'; print_r($_COOKIE); print '</pre>';
?>
```

If I upload that to my server and run it through IE/Edge I don't get any problems. Run it locally however and nothing is ever set. No cookies. I've checked the cookies option which says "Dont block cookies" but I'm a bit confused - is there a security setting somewhere? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You know it takes a reload before a cookie can be read? So you set the cookie but it can't be read because you need to reload the page.
If you reload the page, you set the cookie again, thus it can't be read.

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE)){
   setcookie('my','cookie',0);
}else{
   print '<pre>'; print_r($_COOKIE); print '</pre>';
}
```

So open the page, then press refresh.

EDIT: this has nothing to do with internet explorer, this is how setcookie and PHPs cookie functions work.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

**Common Pitfalls:**

`Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie expires.`

Comment: Yes I do appreciate that. Unfortunately refreshing doesn't fix it.

Comment: That is odd... You mean refreshing **with** my code above or just refreshing? It's actually a big difference. What headers is sent? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg130952(v=vs.85).aspx